# Constructor for must explicity initialize the member which does not have a default constructor

Tags: c++, cinder

I'm trying to fix this error, i am still learning cinder and c++. 
Can someone please help with this. Thank you in advance

Error: 
   "Constructor for 'SerialHandler' must explicity initialize the member 'serial' which does not have a default constructor"

SerialHandler.h

```
class SerialHandler
{
public :
  SerialHandler(){}; // <- error here
  cinder::Serial serial; // <-
  void setup();
  bool isDone;
  bool isonline;
 };
```

SerialHandler.cpp

```
#include "SerialHandler.h"

void SerialHandler::setup()
{
   isDone =true;
   try {
      Serial::Device dev =    Serial::findDeviceByNameContains("cu.usbmodem1411");
      serial.Serial::create( dev, 115200);   
      console() << "Serial Connected" << std::endl;
      isonline =true;
   }
   catch( ... ) {
       console() << "There was an error initializing the serial device!" << std::endl;

       isonline =false;

       const vector<Serial::Device> &devices( Serial::getDevices() );
       for( vector<Serial::Device>::const_iterator deviceIt = devices.begin(); deviceIt != devices.end(); ++deviceIt ) {
       console() << "Device for MAIN?: " << deviceIt->getName() << endl;
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: What's your question? The compiler error tells it's all!

Comment: You need to use the ctor's initialization list to initialize the member which does not have a default ctor (in this case `cinder::Serial`)

Comment: *i am still learning cinder and c++* -- The error was an obvious one.  Shows that trying to use frameworks to learn C++ isn't such a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a bit less straightforward than one might assume from the error message. `cinder::Serial` has a protected constructor, so you cannot even have a `Serial` object as a member of your class.  `Serial::create` is a static member function which returns a `SerialRef` object (which is a shared pointer to an instance of `Serial`).

So your class declaration should have something like:

```
class SerialHandler {
         ...
    cinder::SerialRef serial;
         ...
};
```

And your `create` call in `SerialHandler::setup()` should look like:

```
serial = cinder::Serial::create( dev, 115200);
```